# Trapping a tint

Tags: trapping, flexography

When trapping a tinted color, what's the right move trap it with the same percentage of the tint or the 100% of it ? (in flexography or screen printing to be specific)

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of the area that you are asking about?

Comment: Nothing in particular, ex: shape with a blue tint over another red one the trap of the blue will be tinted as well or the 100 % of the color ?

Answer (score 2):

The trap (or grip as some people like to call it) should be a continuation of the shape that you are trapping, so the overlapping area should always be the same colour and tint as the rest of the shape.

To put to another way; If you were to take away the object that your shape is trapping to, then it should just look like a slightly larger / expanded version of the original (untrapped) shape so you wouldn't expect to see any distinct key line or area of different colour.

Hope that's clear and helpful.

Comment: Technically, that is only one kind of trapping, a "spread" trap, where you make the object larger -- you spread its color into an adjacent area. You can also choke trap, where a surrounding object, like a background color, is brought into the object to trap it. You never want to spread dark text, for example, because it would change its appearance; it's better  to choke the lighter background into the text, which won't distort the letterforms, but will prevent a gap between the colored areas in case of registration problems.